# how to use routerLink instead of href in anchor tag in 'innerHTML' in angular2+?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In **angular 2+**

1. If I'm using **href** to redirect then it **reloads the whole
   page**.

**In .ts**

```
this.htmlText = 'The validation window for <a href=\"http://localhost/nomination/">Innovator Mind</a> nominations is open now. Last date to review is 2020-Jan-25';
```

**in HTML**,

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlText "></div>
```

2. If I'm using **routerlink** to redirect then **routerlink does not
   get render** in html.

**In .ts**

```
this.htmlText = 'The validation window for <a routerLink=\"http://localhost/nomination/">Innovator Mind</a> nominations is open now. Last date to review is 2020-Jan-25';
```

**in HTML**,

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlText"></div>
```

**So how to achieve the route the page without reloading the page?**

Comment: I don't think that you can make a router link inside innerHTML but there are other ways to make routing can you explain a little bit more what you want exactly.

Comment: But _why_ are you putting the entire thing into the template as `innerHTML`?

Comment: it's notification data that comes from server with ancher tag and showing it in innerhtml to render @mbojko

Comment: @NoahLc I just want to redirect the user according to the anchor tag href without reloading the page. and the link data comes from server.

Comment: I think the better way is to make a component who can get links as parameters and create links by loop if you have an example for data that come from the server to help you more. @SahilRalkar

Comment: @NoahLc solved the problem by using imanmadani 's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in constructor.

```
private router: Router
```

Use click event for change url by ts ->

.ts:

```
   html='<a value="myRoute">link</a>';

   changeRoute(value){
     let myRoute=value.target.attributes.value.value;
      if(myRoute){
       this.router.navigate([ myRoute ]);
      }
   }
```

.html :

```
<div (click)='changeRoute($event)' [innerHTML]="html"> </div>
```